# Sci fi short story about interstellar ship with starving robots

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, spaceship, robots

About 2011 I read a short story in an anthology. It described an interstellar ship populated by people that were actually sentient robots; they were made of metal, and yet were starving. I think the story was recent. I'd like to reread it, but don't have the book now, and can't recall its title, or the story's title.

Comment: Where did you read this? U.S.? U.K.? Elsewhere?  Which country published the book?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The *starving robot* concept is so unlikely that I'm going out on a limb and say that you are misremembering the year, and it was 2013 and not 2011. This seems [Bit Rot by Charles Stross](http://www.antipope.org/charlie/fiction/bitrot.html), available online. It made its way into some anthologies, one of them *Engineering Infinity* (on Amazon).

The robots are on a starship bound to Wolf 1061, and they are hit by a gamma ray burst that contaminates their maintenance feedstock, and bodies, with radioactive isotopes. From then on, the basic survival instincts coded in ther *mechanocytes* drive them to prey on each other in search of pure, uncontaminated metals and substances with which to repair themselves.

> "Because the techné I shoved up her marrow is some of the last
>   uncontaminated material on the ship," Wo pointed out acidly. "There
>   are people on this ship who'll crack her bones to feed on it before
>   long. If she stays here I won't be able to protect her."
>
> "But --"
>
> I looked around. Not all the silent occupants of the surgical frames
>   were unconscious. Eyes, glittering in the darkness, tracked me like
>   gunsights. Empty abdominal sacks, bare rib cages, manipulators curled
>   into claws where Doctor-Engineer Wo had flensed away the
>   radiation-damaged tissue. The blind, insensate hunger of primitive
>   survival reflexes -- feed and repair -- stared at me instead of
>   conscious minds. Suddenly my numb feet, the persistent pins and
>   needles in my left arm, acquired a broader perspective.
>
> "They're hungry," explained Wo. "They'll eat you without a second
>   thought, because they've got nothing with which to think it -- not
>   until they've regrown a neural core around their soul chip." It waved
>   the stump of a tentacle at me. "Jordan and Mirabelle have been
>   rounding up the worst cases, bringing them here to dump on me, but
>   they've been increasingly unforthcoming about events outside of late.
>   I think they may be trying to keep themselves conscious by ..." A
>   tentacle uncurled, pointed at the pathetic husk of my remora. "Take
>   your sister and go, Lilith. Stay out of sight and hope for rescue."
>
> "Rescue --"
>
> "Eventually the most demented will die, go into shutdown. Some will
>   recover. If they find feedstock. Once the situation equilibrates, we
>   can see about assembling a skeleton crew to ensure we arrive. Then
>   there'll be plenty of time to prospect for high-purity rare earth
>   elements and resurrect the undead. If there's anything left to
>   resurrect."
>
> "But can't I help --" I began, then I saw the gleam in Wo's
>   photoreceptor. The curl and pulse of tentacles, the sallow
>   discoloration of it's dermal integument. "You're ill too?"
>
> "Take your sister and go away." Wo hissed and rolled upside down,
>   spreading its tentacles radially around it's surgical mouthparts.
>   "Before I eat you: I'm *so hungry*..."

Comment: That's it!  I recognise the title "engineering Infinity," though think I never noted the story's title. I recognise Wolf 1061, and the details about the robots' physiology-like workings.  There was no way I could have recalled the title or author, thank you for saving me from frustration and maybe madness!

Comment: Great! You can mark the answer as accepted then (BTW, you can read the story online at the link I gave to Stross's site).

Comment: Ok, done. Thanks for the help; greatly appreciated (sorry for verbosity, my original was rejected as too few characters)

Comment: Note that if you particularly liked this story, it's set in the same universe as a couple of Stross's novels, *Saturn's Children* and *Neptune's Brood*, that you may also like.  See [his blog entry giving details of the story here](http://www.antipope.org/charlie/blog-static/2013/06/short-story-bit-rot.html).

Comment: I'll check them out, thanks. Always like to find new good stuff.